# How do I stop Google Sheets from refreshing the entire spreadsheet when I first open Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom Google Sheets function that calls an API (using the Google Scripts editor URLFetchApp) The function can take 15-20 seconds to fully complete. Whenever I open the spreadsheet, the function calls again from the beginning, taking 15-20 seconds to fully load all the values. Is there any way to stop this automatic spreadsheet function refresh, and if there isn't, is there a workaround to solve my problem?

Comment: You have a cell formula `=myFunction()` I guess? Remove this and install a button, which on-click will execute your function.

Comment: Buttons are for the peasantry. (jk :D) - Use a menu item. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus